# Windows 10 booting to black screen without mouse pointer and logo

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, dell-inspiron, display-driver

I have a Dell Inspiron 7437.
 I recently upgraded from win 8.1 to win 10 with anniv updates.
 Things worked well for a few days. On one day after I had put the laptop to sleep, it wouldn't wake up.
I shut it down using the power key on the laptop and restarted it. I didn't get the Dell logo on my screen, nor do I see any mouse pointer.
 I was able to however connect to an external display (TV) using a HDMI cable.

I read on a Microsoft forum that you probably need to rollback to your old graphics driver, so I uninstalled it from control panel and restarted the system. Now, I can't even connect to an external display :( I don't have any recovery media with me as well. The good thing is I have a backup of all my personal data, I did this before I upgraded to win 10.

Note: The <kbd>f8</kbd> key, power + <kbd>D</kbd> key and other combinations have no effect on startup. I don't know how I can change the boot sequence, since the designated  <kbd>f2</kbd>key for dell also has no effect.

I assume my laptop display isn't damaged as such and it is just a software driver issue.
Is there any way I can get back to win 10 or even win 8.1?

Comment: if you went from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 Version 1607, if you can navigate within Windows enough, you can indeed roll back to Windows 8.1 for 15 days.

Comment: I cannot see anything at all on my screen, like I said in my question. I only see a black screen without any mouse pointer or anything for that matter. I dont know why this was downvoted !

Comment: I understand you have a black screen, but you also indicate that " I was able to however connect to an external display(TV) using a hdmi cable.", which seems to indicate you can log into your installation.  *I am not obligated to explain my vote..*  You can boot into Safe Mode if you force WIndows 10, to fail to load, at least three times.  You can also get to Adance Startup with a Version 1607 .ISO

Comment: Well my present situation  as quoted in my question is this - " I read on a microsoft forum that you probably need to rollback to your old graphics driver, so I uninstalled it from control panel and restarted the system . Now, I can't even connect to an external display :( " I am on Black Screen now !

Comment: Your question is confusing to read.  You still have things you can do.  If you can't get into Windows to reverse the upgrade, then you would have to install Windows 10 again, of course a driver issue is likely to repeat itself.  *You can't fix this unless you can boot into Safe Mode or you have a Version 1607 ISO*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now solved, it was a hardware issue - the lcd display cable was the culprit .  I ran checkdisk by attaching the laptop hd to a desktop PC using the same SATA cable. This helped me get back my external display HDMI to TV, then I ran the preboot system assessment (ePSA) which pointed towards a faulty lcd cable. Got that replaced and it finally worked !